# using attach(this); in a GUI program

Tags: java, model-view-controller, user-interface

I'm looking at a GUI program made using MVC and they have this method. What does this method do and when will you need to use it?

```
attach(this);
```

Here is one of the classes with the method.

```
import model.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.text.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class IncomePanel extends JPanel implements View
{   private Stadium stadium;
    private JLabel label;

public IncomePanel(Stadium stadium)
{   this.stadium = stadium;
    for (Group group: stadium.seats())
        group.attach(this);
    setup();
    build(); }

private void setup()
{   setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());    }

private void build()
{   label = new JLabel(income());
    label.setForeground(Color.blue);
    add(label); }

public void update()
{   label.setText(income());  }

private String income()
{   return "Income is $" + twoDec(stadium.income());    }

private String twoDec(double value)
{   DecimalFormat twoD = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
    return twoD.format(value); }
}
```

Comment: Method of which class? VirtualMachine? You need to give us a little more information.

Comment: Other classes with an `attach` method: SelectionKey, TransportService and AttachingConnector, though not all of their methods can take "this" as an argument.

Comment: That's not the class with the `attach` method, that's a class that uses a class with an `attach` method. What's the namespace for `Group`? Is it from `model`? If so, it's probably internal to the application and thus unknown by most of the people who aren't co-developers of yours.

Answer (score 0):

Look inside the `model` package which is part of your project. In there you'll find a file named `group.java`. It contains the source for the Group class or interface.

All this snippet tells us is that Group's `attach` method takes an `IncomePanel` as an argument. If you want to find out what it does with it you have to look at the Group file.